# pyinstaller missing mxnet dll

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller, mxnet

I've been trying to create a simple *.exe* file to receive a parameter and return the output of a my net, in alternative to use a C++ wrapper.

I'm using pyinstaller because it's the one that has worked better for me in the past.

Right now I'm only building a *.py* file only with the imports but I'm already getting the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Cannot find the MXNet library.
List of candidates:
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI52802\mxnet\libmxnet.dll
...
```

My imports.py

```
import time
import numpy as np
import mxnet as mx
from mxnet import gluon, autograd, nd
from mxnet.gluon import nn, rnn
import string
import cv2
import glob
import time
import model
```

**What I've tried:**

- Using pyinstaller in python 3.6/3.5/3.4;
- Edit the *.spec* and adding the *dll* missing to the binaries list;
- Adding mxnet as a hidden import.

Regards.

Comment: I guess in python you actually use bindings to the dll which is provided by MXNet. Is this library actually installed? After you run PyInstaller do you see this dll in output folder? You can also try some tool like Sysinternals ProcMon to see where python interpreter tries to look for this dll.

Comment: It is installed, although I cannot find it at the pyinstaller output build folder. I have not tried to see where it's looking for it as the error tells me that it's trying to find it in the temp folder. The bindings are a possibility, I don't know how the pyinstaller will respond and it's maybe a complex approach to use mxnet. Thanks for the ideas.

Comment: Were you able to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is the line of MXNet that looks to be throwing the exception: https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/blob/c6b1fd5a74152b64f92a8b76e1d28f4c0d4f00cd/python/mxnet/libinfo.py#L73

This means you'll need to set your library path ($PATH) on Windows to include the directory containing MXNet.

It's odd that MXNet is installed in the temp directory. I would suggest using Pip or Conda to install MXnet as per mxnet.io's installation instructions.

https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/versions/master/install/windows_setup.html

Answer (score 1):

I'll give my solution. I've Anaconda on my PC.

If mxnet is installed in Lib\site-packages\mxnet, you need to create a hook-mxnet.py file with this content:

> from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import get_package_paths
>
> datas = [(get_package_paths('mxnet')[1],"mxnet"),]

and copy this file into your PyInstaller folder:

Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks

When you run pyinstaller, you need to add the path of mxnet with the -p option:

> pyinstaller myApp.py -p ''your-path-to-this-point''\Lib\site-packages

It will copy the entire mxnet folder into your dist output folder.
I hope this help...

Answer (score 0):

Find the `datas` attribute in your spec file, and edit it as follows:

```
datas=[('venv/Lib/site-packages/mxnet/*.dll', 'mxnet')]
```